# jQuery - selected option value contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an if statement where I'm trying to set a variable if the selected value of a select element does not contain "ALL"

Here's the code I've tried, but it always returns "%"...

```
if(!$("select.mySelect option:selected").filter(":contains('ALL')")) {
    selected_option = $("select.mySelect option:selected");
} else {
    selected_option = "%";
}
```

HTML

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="ALLTYPE1">All type 1</option>
    <option value="CAR">Car</option>
    <option value="VAN">Van</option>
    <option value="ALLTYPE2">All type 2</option>
    <option value="PLANE">Plane</option>
    <option value="HELICOPTER">Helicopter</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the corresponding HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. `.filter()` will never *return* a false value - it'll always be a jQuery collection - which can be empty, but never false. To test it there are any elements in the jQuery collection returned by `.filter()`, use the `.length` property.

Use:

```
if($("select.mySelect option:selected").filter(":contains('ALL')").length === 0) {
    ...
```

### JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/egEX8/

Comment: +1: (Beat me by seconds!) have added the fiddle anyway to your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to check that the value contains "ALL"??

Comment: Yes. You can use `.text().toLowerCase().indexOf('all') !== -1`

Comment: i.e. `if($("select.mySelect option:selected").text().toLowerCase().indexOf('all') !== -1)`

Comment: wouldn't .text() return the text and not the value?

Comment: For the value, you can use `.val()` and for the option text, you can use `.text()`